# How to set the text on the "save" button in Windows' file dialog?

Tags: winapi, dialog

I'm trying to set the text on the "save" button of the Windows "Save file as..." dialog.

I've set up the hook, received the message, found the button (nb. If I call "`GetWindowText()`" I see "&Save" so I know it's the right button).

Next I changed the text using "`SetWindowText()`" (and called "`GetWindowText()`" to check it - the text is correct).

But ... the button still says "Save".

I can change the "Cancel" button using the exact same code - no problem. What's so special about the "Save" button? How can I change it.

Code (for what it's worth):

```
static UINT_PTR CALLBACK myHook(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
  if (msg == WM_INITDIALOG) {
    wchar_t temp[100];
    HWND h = GetDlgItem(GetParent(hwnd),IDOK);
    GetWindowTextW(h,temp,100);     // temp=="&Save"
    SetWindowTextW(h,L"Testing");
    GetWindowTextW(h,temp,100);     // temp=="Testing"
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on this information, it sounds like the button is being changed after the WM_INITDIALOG.  Isn't there a built-in extension mechanism that allows you to customize aspects of the dialog (without using hooks)?

Comment: I tried looking at the button's text in every call to my callback (there's quite a few calls made after WM_INITDIALOG...). The text always says "Testing" (but it's not the same as what's being displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work....

I'm pretty sure there's something funny going on with the "Save" button but this code will wrestle it into submission:

```
// I replace the dialog's WindowProc with this
static WNDPROC oldProc = NULL;
static BOOL CALLBACK buttonSetter(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Set the button text on every window redraw....
    if (msg == WM_ERASEBKGND) {
        SetDlgItemTextW(hwnd,IDOK,L"OK");
    }
    return oldProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
};

// This is the callback for the GetWriteName hook
static UINT_PTR CALLBACK GWNcallback(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND dlg = GetParent(hwnd);
    if (msg == WM_INITDIALOG) {
        oldProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(dlg, GWL_WNDPROC);
        if (oldProc !=0) {
            SetWindowLongPtr(dlg, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)buttonSetter);
        }
    }
    // We need extra redraws to make our text appear...
    InvalidateRect(dlg,0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to redraw the window after setting the text.

Try calling UpdateWindow() after setting the text.

Answer (score 0):

Use CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT message to set the text rather than mess with SetWindowText directly, i.e.

```
SendMessage(hwnd, CDM_SETCONTROLTEXT, IDOK, L"Testing");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646960(VS.85).aspx has more on customizing open/save dialogs

Comment: Tried that as well...

nb. I can set the text of the "Cancel" button perfectly well using the exact same code (swapping IDOK for IDCANCEL, obviously".

The "Save" button seems to be doing something weird.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?  Can you post the code you use to invoke the save dialog?